# Google guava iterables.filter, type errors related to generics?

Tags: java, generics, guava, iterable

I have a custom predicate that has a signiture as follows:

```
public class ELPredicate<T> implements Predicate<T>
```

I am attempting to filter them in a function similar to this:

```
public List<ComponentDefinition> filterComponents(String expression, List<ComponentDefinition> definitions) {

    if (definitions == null || definitions.size() == 0) {
        return new ArrayList<ComponentDefinition>();
    }

    ELPredicate<ComponentDefinition> predicate = new ELPredicate<>(expression);
    return Lists.newArrayList(Iterables.filter(definitions, predicate));
}
```

but i get this error:

```
The method filter(Iterable<T>, Predicate<? super T>) in the type Iterables is not applicable for the arguments (List<ComponentDefinition>, ELPredicate<ComponentDefinition>)
```

from what (I think) I know:

- Lists are iterable,
- `<ComponentDefinition>` is `<? super ComponentDefinition>`
- I am doing this in unit tests without any problem.

what's going on?

Comment: This sounds a lot like the errors you'd get if you were importing Predicate or List from the wrong place?

Comment: That should work... Like @LouisWasserman says, you probably have an import wrong (most likely `Predicate`, that should be `com.google.common.base.Predicate`).

Comment: the ELPredicate imports from com.google.common.base.Predicate and where it's used only imports the extending predicate. List is from java.util and Lists is from the google commons package. This was one of the first things I thought of.

Comment: btw, `return FluentIterable.from(definitions).filter(new ELPredicate<>(expression)).toList();` is more concise.

Comment: @卢声远ShengyuanLu `new ELPredicate<>(expression)` will infer `<Object>` instead of `<ComponentDefinition>` in that context.  You'd have to write `new ELPredicate<ComponentDefinition>()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, my problem was an access issue rather than a type issue. I was attempting to filter a private inner class (for testing purposes) and java apparently doesn't like that. I made it public and everything worked as expected.